# stargazer summary.stat relabel column headings

Tags: r, label, summary, stargazer

Is it possible to relabel column headings for summary.stats in stargazer?  The default labels seem to ignore my preferred labels.  Thanks in advance!

```
library(stargazer)
stargazer(attitude, 
           column.labels = c("Obs", "P25", "P50", "P75"),
           summary.stat = c("n", "p25", "median", "P75")
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the `column.labels` command only applies to regression tables created with stargazer. However, since stargazer can also directly output dataframes, you can create your own dataframe containing the desired summary statistics with the names you want them to have, like so:

```
library(stargazer)
# create data frame first, set nrow to number of your variables
dfdescriptives <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 3, ncol = 0))

# specify the variables you want to summarize here
vars <- attitude[, c("var1","var5","id")]

# assign inteligible variable names as rownames
row.names(dfdescriptives) <- c("Variable 1", "Variable 5", "ID Variable")

# get number of observations for each variable
dfdescriptives$Obs <- apply(vars, 2, function(x) sum(complete.cases(x)))
# get 25th percentile for each variable
dfdescriptives$P25 <- apply(vars, 2, function(x) summary(x)[[2]])
# get median for each variable
dfdescriptives$P50 <- apply(vars, 2, function(x) summary(x)[[3]])
# get 75th percentile for each variable
dfdescriptives$P75 <- apply(vars, 2, function(x) summary(x)[[5]])

# output dataframe directly w/o summary
stargazer(dfdescfull, summary = FALSE, header = FALSE, 
      title = "Descriptive Statistics as I would like to call them.",
      notes = c("Source: stackoverflow.com"))
```